# Need a Zend_Form_Element that only stores a value

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I have an array of options for a select list.

```
$options = array( 1=>'Option1', 2=>... );
```

But if I only have one option, I rather want either:

1. A hidden `<input type="hidden" name="opt" value="2"/>` with a validator requiring the posted value to be `2`
2. No output. The value will only be stored in the form_element/form until requested by `$form->getValues()`

This code is a non-working example of what I want: (`$this` is a Zend_Form object)

```
$first_val = reset(array_keys($options));

if( count($options) > 1 )
    $this->addElement('select', 'opt', array(
        'multiOptions' => $options,
        'label' => 'Options',
        'value' => $first_val,              
        'required' => true ));
else
    $this->addElement('hidden', 'opt', array(
        'required' => true,
        'value' => $first_val ));
```

However, the value will not validate to `$first_val`. Anyone may change the hidden value, allowing them to inject invalid values. This is **not** acceptable.

Help?

Comment: you have not set a validator for the hidden field.

Comment: @hakre What kind of validator should I set then?

Comment: A fitting one, so one that checks for the value you need to look for. You might need to write a custom one, or if there is a min/max one, you can set both values to the same value, see http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html and http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.elements.html

Comment: True, the min/max would work. But it feels like a workaround for something that should be possible to do in a more elegant way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a custom Zend_Form_Element that does exactly what I want. Maybe someone else might find it useful:

```
<?php
require_once 'Zend/Form/Element.php';

/**
* Class that will automatically validate against currently set value.
 */
class myApp_Element_Stored extends Zend_Form_Element
{
    /**
     * Use formHidden view helper by default
     * @var string
     */
    public $helper = 'formHidden';

    /**
     * Locks the current value for validation
     */
    public function lockValue()
    {
        $this->addValidator('Identical', true, (string)$this->getValue());
        return $this;
    }

    public function isValid($value, $context = null)
    {
        $this->lockValue();
        return parent::isValid($value, $context);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

your code is missing a validator, e.g. [Zend_Validate_Identical](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.identical)

Comment: I can't get it to work with `Zend_Validate_Identical`. Any code suggestion?
I was hoping `Zend_Form_Element_Hidden` had a built in validation similar to `Zend_Form_Element_Hash`.

Comment: @ANisus: You tell a valid point here, now I better understand your question. But I assume Zend Framework is not adding the identical validator to hidden fields automatically. That's probably worth for a feature request.